# connections in the connection manager disappears -visual-studio-code Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.0

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I upgraded visual studio 2019 to visual studio 2022 professional.
I could connect to azure repo successfully. I am trying to open the ssis package in VS 2022 and don't see any connections for that project in the connection manager.
I tried to open the script task in the package and get the following error.

Error:

> The task with the name "Gather Stage File_id and MigrateFlag" and the creation name "SSIS.ReplacementTask" is not registered for use on this computer.
> Contact Information:
> Execute SQL Task; Microsoft Corporation; SQL Server 2014; © 2014 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1

I am not sure how to get all my previous connections in the connection manager.

Can you please help me fix/figure this issue?

[image]

[image]